# Django OneToOneRelation

Tags: django

I have three models in django as follows :

```
class Type(models.Model):
    limit = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    default = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Subscription(models.Model):
    started = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    type = models.OneToOneField(Type)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type.name


class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    active = models.BooleanField()
    subscription = models.OneToOneField(Subscription)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want that one member can have only one subscription and that one subscription can have only one type. But when I try to create a member with a subscription type that already exists, I get an error.

I could maybe do it as follows :

```
class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    active = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Subscription(models.Model):
    started = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    member = models.OneToOneField(Member)

class Type(models.Model):
    limit = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    default = models.BooleanField()
    subscription = models.OneToOneField(Subscription)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

But then I cannot choose subscription when I try to add a member in django admin.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a user to have one subscription, but one subscription to be used by many users, you don't want a one-to-one at all; you want a standard ForeignKey. This will give you exactly what you want:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    ...
    subscription = models.ForeignKey(Subscription)
```